# How to prevent user editing a specific column while still having write access to the object on Parse?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have some specific columns on my `_User` class that I want to edit only with master key at the server side. My User does have write access to itself. Is there a way to prevent my user from editing specific columns, for example, let's say I have a user object and I want user to prevent editing its own points:

```
before save trigger:
 if(points field have been changed by the user){
  response.error();
 )
```

It doesn't have to be in before save trigger, but I highly doubt there is any other point to check such "dirty" column, if any. Is there a way to achieve what I need (other than obvious solutions such as creating a new class, setting it's ACL to none, holding a user pointer and a score column and editing that only with master key)?

Comment: How would your user manually change the points? Your app should be able to keep that locked down. Are you worried that people will reverse-engineer your code and call the REST API?

Comment: @mbm29414 I never, ever deploy security measures client-side. what you are saying is extremely easy for someone who knows what they are doing, and points is just an example. In the actual app, it will be a value of something that you buy with actual money.

Comment: What I meant was that, for most users, if the app doesn't do it, they can't do it. Not so much a security measure, though, I agree. If it's that important, I'd pull it out into a separate class and only manage it in Cloud Code with Master Key.

Comment: @mbm29414 if that's the only way, I'll go that way. But maybe there is some Parse feature like `obj.isDirty(column)` that I can simply use, which will make my job MUCH easier.

Comment: Well, there's this: http://www.parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Object.html#dirty

Comment: Coupled with this: https://www.parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide?language=JavaScript#functions-modifysave

Comment: @mbm29414 this is exactly what I've been looking for! I knew about dirty, but missed that optional argument part, I thought it only acted on the whole object :)

Comment: @mbm29414 could you post it as an answer so I can give the credit :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the [Parse JavaScript Documentation related to "dirty" objects and properties.](http://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Object.html#dirty)

> {Boolean} dirty(attr)
>
> Returns true if this object has been modified since its last save/refresh. If an attribute is specified, it returns true only if that particular attribute has been modified since the last save/refresh.
>
> Parameters:
>   {String} attr
>
> An attribute name (optional).
>
> Returns:
>   {Boolean}

If you couple that bit (calling `dirty("score")` with a [beforeSave() Cloud Code function](https://www.parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions-modifysave)), you should get what you want.

> Modifying Objects On Save
>
> In some cases, you don't want to throw out invalid data. You just want to tweak it a bit before saving it. beforeSave can handle this case, too. You just call response.success on the altered object.
>
> In our movie review example, we might want to ensure that comments aren't too long. A single long comment might be tricky to display. We can use beforeSave to truncate the comment field to 140 characters:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Review", function(request, response) {
    var comment = request.object.get("comment");
    if (comment.length > 140) {
        // Truncate and add a ...
       request.object.set("comment", comment.substring(0, 137) + "...");
    }
    response.success();
});
```